# python module / package sharing

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, package

I have a flask app that uses functions from custom modules.

My File hierarchy is like so:

```
__init__.py
    ec2/__init__.py
    citrixlb/__init__.py
```

So far in the root `__init__.py` I have a `from ec2 import *` clause to load my module.

Now I'm adding a new 'feature' called citrixlb.

Both the of the `__init__.py` files in citrixlb and ec2 use some of the same functions to do their task.

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
__init__.py
    common/__init__.py
    ec2/__init__.py
    citrixlb/__init__.py
```

If I do the above,and move all common functions to `common/__init__.py`, how would `ec2/__init__.py` and `citrixlb/__init__.py` get access to the functions
in `common/__init__.py`?

The reason is that

- I would like to keep the root `__init__.py` as sparse as possible
- I wish to be able to run the `__init__.py` in `citrixlb` and `ec2` as 
  standalone scripts.
- I also wish to be able to continue to add functionality by adding `newdir/__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

> If I do the above,and move all common functions to `common/__init__.py`, how would `ec2/__init__.py` and `citrixlb/__init__.py` get access to the functions in `common/__init__.py`?

This is exactly what [explicit relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html) were designed for:

```
from .. import common
```

Or, if you insist on using `import *`:

```
from ..common import *
```

---

You can do this with absolute import instead. Assuming your top-level package is named `mything`:

```
from mything import common
from mything.common import *
```

But in this case, I think you're better with the relative version. It's not just more concise and easier to read, it's more robust (if you rename `mything`, or reorganize its structure, or embed this whole package inside a larger package…). But you may want to read the rationales for the two different features in [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) to decide which one seems more compelling to you here.

---

One thing:

> I wish to be able to run the `__init__.py` in `citrixlb` and `ec2` as standalone scripts.

That, you can't do. Running modules inside a package as a top-level script is not supposed to work. Sometimes you get away with it. Once you're importing from a sibling or a parent, you definitely will not get away with it.

The right way to do it is either:

- `python -m mything.ec2` instead of `python mything/ec2/__init__.py`
- Write a trivial `ec2` script at the top level, that just does something like `from mything.ec2 import main; main()`.

The latter is a common enough pattern that, if you're building a `setuptools` distribution, it can build the `ec2` script for you automatically. And automatically make it still work even `ec2` ends up in `/usr/local/bin` while the `mything` package is in your `site-packages`. See [`console_scripts`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#console-scripts) for more details.